# How to set up reminders to complete tasks in VSTS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

Is anyone able to suggest the best way to set up a recurring reminder within a VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services) project? I want it to act like an Outlook Calendar recurring reminder that the whole team gets once per week.

I've looked at creating a Story / Epic / Feature and trying to assign a recurring team reminder to that but can't see a way to do it. The task concerned would be ongoing so in an ideal world of someone new to VSTS, I'd create one of the aforementioned things, set a recurring reminder on it, the team do the task when the reminder comes up and add a note. And that continues until we switch it off.

I've had a look online but can't find anything as yet.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing that comes close is a dashboard widget that uses @me in its query.

VSTS doesn't have a scheduled reminder or alert system.

You can probably cobble something together using the REST API and a scheduled build. Calling a work item query and sending email is pretty easy from PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

As jessehouwing said that you can do it through Scheduled build, there are some extensions related to email in VSTS marketplace, such as [Send Email](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask).

On the other hand, there is Outlook add-in extension: [TeamCompanion For Outlook](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ekobit.TeamCompanion#).